# Can an ArrayList be null and have a size > 0?

Tags: java

I was reviewing a Java project and saw the following code:

```
List<XYZ> xyzList = new ArrayList<>();

............................
do some things with the list
............................

if (xyzList != null && xyzList.size() > 0) doSomething();
```

Is there any case where a list can be null but have a size greater than 0? Or is this redundant and equivalent to `if (xyzList.size() > 0)`?

EDIT: xyzList can be modified from an outside class, so the null check is definitely needed. Thanks for responses, I've just had a long day and my mind was not functioning.

Comment: Short circuit logic.  The first check _guarantees_ a non-null list.  The second then checks its size (which would throw an exception on a null list).

Comment: No but you get npe if you call .size() on null

Comment: What happens is the JVM won't bothering checking the second part of the boolean expression if the first is false.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I think you should post up your answer too

Comment: Also, the `null` check is redundant (unless "do some things with the list" is setting the reference to `null`). If `xyzList` were a method argument, you could avoid the check by asserting non-nullness by annotating the argument with `@Nonnull`, in combination with [`checkNotNull()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull%28T%29). Failing early with an NPE is better than to have `null` checks all over your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code is ensuring that `xyzList` is not null before calling `size()` on it which would result in a crash/exception.
Because of short circuit evaluation, `size()` will not be called in the `if` clause when `xyzList` is null

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I asked this. I really need to take a break. I will accept your answer when the time is up.

Comment: No problem @JosueEspinosa. We all have those kind of days.

Comment: what would happen if you checked size first ? I think the question is kind of ... :)

Comment: @KickButtowski - it would throw an exception if xyzList is null

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy to me, op's question does not make sense at all because you are trying to check two different things which are not even related together. so what u think?

Comment: @KickButtowski:  They're related.  You can't dereference `null`, and `null` doesn't mean `empty`.

Comment: @Makoto I totally agree with you but again you are checking two different things. first check if the obj is there and after check the size which to me is gonna be two different issues. :)

Comment: @KickButtowski:  You can't check the size of something that isn't defined.

Answer (score 3):

An object must exist before you can dereference anything on it.  This is what is being got at with the null-check:  we want to be sure that `xyzList` exists *before* we start doing anything on it.

That said, depending on where it was declared, this check may be frivolous.

If you see this on a field that is declared `final`, then the field could be considered **eagerly initialized**, and because it's `final`, you could guarantee that it will *never* get set back to null.

```
private final List<XYZ> xyzList = new ArrayList<>(); // guaranteed not null
```

If you see this in a method, and there are no mutations to the variable at all to set it to a null value, then the null check is pointless, as again - it is not going to change for the lifecycle of that method.

```
public void someMethod() {
    List<XYZ> xyzList = new ArrayList<>();
    // do other operations without reassigning xyzList
    // null check is useless since the variable is initialized to
    // a non-null value
    if(xyzList != null && !xyzList.empty()) {
        // operation with list
    }
}
```

This sort of pattern is done on variables which are not guaranteed to be initialized.  If you're eagerly initializing a variable or field, then there's no need to perform this check.

Answer (score 1):

If `do some things with the list` does not involve setting it to null, then the null check is redundant. A good IDE will spot this while you type and warn you of it.

Otherwise the null check ensures that the size check does not produce a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what

```
............................
do some things with the list
............................
```

is doing, but my guess is that "xyzList != null && xyzList.size() > 0" are called together because you don't want to end up calling  a method on a null reference. Hence, it is not redundant

Answer (score 0):

**An Array list can't be NULL & 0 at same time.**

But it doesn't meant that a not null array list always have size > 0.
 Array list which is Not Null, can also have size 0.

- Always ensure that ArrayList is not null before calling arrayList.size(), to avoid null pointer exception.

example:

```
if (workImageArrayList != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "size : " + workImageArrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //can show ---> size : 0, but its not null.
} else {
    Log.e("WorkImageArrayList", "" + workImageArrayList);
    //arraylist is null.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line construct a new empty ArrayList object with size = 0 and make the xyzList pointer points to that object.

```
List<XYZ> xyzList = new ArrayList<>();
```

xyzList pointer is null when it does not point to any object.

```
List<XYZ> xyzList;
```

Therefore, an ArrayList can either be null or have a size > 0, not both